# Vector iterator not dereferencable in for loop

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using a loop to count how many times that a word was entered then print the word and how many times it was entered, which works but it never prints the last word, I have it sorted alphabetically. Before the last word is printed it errors out saying the iterator is not dereferencable. Here is my code for the loop:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == *(it+1))
        {
        count++;
        }
        else if (*it != *(it+1))
        {
                count++;
            cout << *it << " ---- " << count << endl;
            count=0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior - imagine `it` is pointing to the last element of `v`, then you are trying to dereference `v.end()` in `*(it+1)`

```
if (*it != *(it+1)
```

STL iterator, end doesn't point to last element; end() returns an iterator that represents the end of the elements in the container. The end is the position *behind* the last element. Such an iterator is also called a *past-the-end iterator*.

Thus, begin() and end() define a *half-open* range that includes the first element but **excludes** the last

```
 --------------------------------
 |  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 --------------------------------
  /\                               /\      
begin()                            end()
```

For what you are trying to achieve, have a look at [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)

```
auto it = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end());

if (it != v.end())
{
  count ++;
}
else
{
   cout << *it << " ---- " << count << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when `it == v.end() - 1`, you deference `(it+1)` so `v.end()`,
and deference `v.end()` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When you are at the last word and try to execute:

`if (*it == *(it+1))`

`it+1` is pointing at `v.end()`, which is a valid iterator, but is not derefernceable. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

When it is one before the end iterator, you have a problem here: `*(it+1)` as this attempts to dereference the end iterator, which is invalid.

I'm not sure what you want your logic to do in this case, but you can check for this with `if (it+1 != v.end())` before doing your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Because when `it` is near end, `it+1` is at end, and you trying to dereference it in `if` operator.