# Vector iterator not dereferencable for a wrapper class (Without beyond the end() dereferencing)

Tags: c++

I was trying to understand the behavior of Argument Dependent Lookup in case of range-based for loop. I implement the begin and end for my type as free functions within the same namespace as my type. I keep getting runtime assertion failed error.

> Expression: vector iterator not dereferncable

Here is the sample code that I'd written:

```
namespace my {
    struct MyType {
        std::vector<int> hiddenData;
        MyType(int i) : hiddenData(i) {}
    };

    auto begin(MyType obj) {
        return obj.hiddenData.begin();
    }

    auto end(MyType obj) {
        return obj.hiddenData.end();
    }
}

void test() {
    my::MyType m(5);
    for (auto& e : m)
        std:: cout << e << std:: endl;
}
```

Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector iterator not dereferencable in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636941/vector-iterator-not-dereferencable-in-for-loop)

Comment: They just bypass the call to underlying vector's begin() and end(). I see that they could be a problem, but I have no explicit reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue:

`auto begin(MyType obj)`

MyType is a temporary object.  Thus this object no longer exists when the function returns, therefore the iterator being returned is invalid.

Instead, pass a reference:

`auto begin(MyType& obj)`

`auto end(MyType& obj)`